# How do I calculate deformant and real power of this circuit?

Tags: diodes, power-electronics, three-phase, full-bridge

I have this circuit, the load is RL:
[image: circuit]

[image: Load Voltage (CH1) and current]
[image: Source voltage(ch1) and current]

I need to calculate the apparent, real, reactive and deformant power assuming L is very large. Since L is very large that means Q= 0 var and Pload=~Uav*Iav and S=3*Urms*Irms. My problem is how to calculate real power and deformant power.

Comment: I assume that by "deformant" you mean what we'd call "harmonic" or "harmonic energy" in English (I like "deformant", though -- it's very descriptive).  Since this looks like a homework problem, can you show us what work you've done so far?

Comment: @TimWescott I think to calculate de real power I have to multiply the source rms voltage by the first harmonic rms current times 3. And then the de harmonic energy I take the square root of apparent power squared minus real power squared. The problem is getting the value of that first harmonic

Comment: Or, you can look all the way back at *why* RMS is used.  I can look at your bottom O-scope trace, and for that leg, I can pretty much calculate the instantaneous real power in my head.  With a pencil and paper, I could calculate the real power over one cycle.  Can you see how I might do that?

Comment: but isn't that power the apparent?

Comment: Real power is the power that's actually doing something.  It's not just looking spectacular on a meter, or swishing back and forth in a wire; it's actually turning a motor or heating something, etc.  Apparent power is what appears, at a glance, to be the power.  So -- what's the **real** power?

Comment: Oh ok, so the real power is the load power